# Worry about oversized check in luggage

Tags: europe, luggage, international-travel, check-in

I just bought a Samsonite poly-carbonate check in suitcase called Enorme 79 spinner. The dimension quoted in the specs is 22 X 31 X 15 (Inches) that adds up to 68. But the airlines allow only up to 62. When I asked the dealer he said the quoted dimensions include the expandable 5 inches and I can use without expanding the luggage volume.

I am traveling from India to Aarhus, Denmark through KLM airlines.

Should I expect any issues w.r.t. checking in this suitcase?

Comment: 68-5=63 so you're still out by one inch. I'd love to see airline staff measure it though.

Comment: People say that an extra 1-2 inches will not matter. But I need to know if I should exchange the bag for a smaller one or this should be fine.

Comment: The staff consider weight more than size

Comment: I measured it myself and I found it less actually. It comes around 160 cm (~63 inches) without expanding. But you know the measurements vary person to person.

Comment: Anyways thank you all for your suggestions. I exchanged mine for a better model (Samsonite S'cure) which is below the size limits. It is to better to  pay more for a better model than to pay airlines for checking in an over-sized luggage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why risk it? Logically one of three happens:

- they just take it
- they charge a fee (which is most likely larger in airport than in advance)
- they don't take it

And if you have several flights then the dice will roll for each one.

KLM site says that you **"need"** to reserve oversized baggage in advance, in addition to paying a fee:

> For larger [than 62 in] and/or heavier items you will need to **pay a fee** and you always **need to reserve for transportation** via KLM Telephone Reservations - as early as possible, but no later than 48 hours before departure. If you would like to bring an item larger than 300 cm (l+w+h) or heavier than 32 kg, you will need to ask for approval via KLM Telephone Reservations.
>
> [Special baggage - KLM.com](http://www.klm.com/travel/il_en/prepare_for_travel/baggage/exceptional_baggage/index.htm)

So airline has very clear rules for this case. Ignoring them is just gambling. How risky of a gamble though it would be hard to reliably determine.

Answer (score 4):

The bottom line, the airline has rules AND the airline can enforce those rules.  So the question really is, do you want to risk having to pay over-sized bag fees?

Just because Joe B and Mary S got away with it, doesn't mean you will get lucky. Because of my work I travel with bags that surpass the limit by a little bit.  On my favorite airline I get away with it because I have mega elite status, but on other carriers I have had to pay over-sized fees on different occasions.

Comment: How much is a little bit?

Comment: Same experience for me. Slight oversize as in 1 inch too much in every direction.

Comment: @JoErNanO - 3 inches on the girth

Comment: Ultimately, be it weight or size, the decision to allow an oversized bag or not lies with the agent checking you in for the flight.  And to assume that they will look the other way is just inviting disappointment and a later forum post complaining about having to pay that fee.